# Alien movie where the spaceship crashed and repaired itself like reptile skin

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I watched this movie a long time ago. I remember the aliens come to Earth because of DNA and showed some humans the family tree showing special DNA on it. The ship crashed and was repairing itself. I really want to know the title. :(

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Please take a look at the prompts in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and then [edit] your question to add any further details you may recall. The more info you can give us, the better the chances that someone will be able to ID this for you. In particular, it'd be helpful to know in roughly which year you watched this, and when you think it might've been made.

Comment: Also, if anyone correctly identifies the movie you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: How those aliens look like? And their ship? Who was MC? Was there any fights/lasers/rockets/etc?